why there is '/**' value in uri tag under http.server.requests metrics?
Does anyone know why there is '/**' value in uri tag under http.server.requests metrics in spring boot actuator metrics ? I am using spring boot 3, micrometer and spring-boot-starter-actuator for monitoring my application.
Actually when I tried to implement micrometer tracing for distributed tracing and exporting traces to gcp, I'm getting traces for '/**' uri which i don't need. So i was wondering why it is generating in the first place.

Instrumentation in Spring Framework does this, this is intended behavior.
This happens if you call an endpoint that does not exists (e.g.: no mvc mapping and you end up with 404). It is because the uri tag has low cardinality, if you are interested in the raw url (high cardinality), you should find it under the http.url tag.
